# How much space is one row taking up

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to find out how much disk space a single row is taking up in a table.  I can then use this as an approximate to work out how much disk space I can recover by removing old unneeded data.  Would I have to combine all of the columns in a single `SELECT` statement, like so?

```
SELECT DATALENGTH([Id]) + DATALENGTH([Column1]) + DATALENGTH([Column2]) AS 'Size'
  FROM [MyTable]
```

Or is there a better, more efficient way that I'm not aware of?

**EDIT**

I have just noticed that if a column has a `NULL` value, then I get `NULL` as the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Row Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227438/sql-server-row-length)

Comment: Also see http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/A-Simple-Start-Table-Creation-Best-Practices.aspx

Comment: See [this question][1] on SO for some suggestions.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227438/sql-server-row-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much data do you have?

Personally, I'd do one of

- try it on a test system and check "before" and "after"
- just remove unused data because by definition, it isn't needed

The questions is complicated when you have

- variable length data: how much of the field is used on average?
- page density (rows per page) may not increase therefore you save no space
- indexes duplicate a column value, so you have to count some ones twice

So, I'd do it empirically rather than by calculation...

Comment: IMO best method to get what OP is after is to look at the table as a whole...`sp_spaceused` to get total footprint/rowcount = avg space per row.

Comment: @JNK: er.. good point. I overlooked the obvious there...